# React Sigma Bug with force, forceatlas2 and noverlap layouts

Tags: reactjs, sigma.js

I have been running into an issue with react sigma where when I try to use the force, forceatlas2 or the noverlap layouts, my code gives an error when it renders saying this:[image]

I am not having the issue when I use the circular layout. I have followed the method of applying a layout from the docs so I don't know what I should do to fix this. Does anyone know of a solution to this?